# Bitcoin Core not displaying my account balance, can't do anything with it

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoin-core-development, balance

Over a month ago on , I tried to send my balance from my Bitcoin Core wallet to another wallet on a different client, but I had accidentally set a really low transaction fee, leading to the transaction never going through. I expected after it was dropped from the Mem pool, the balance would show in the wallet, but Core isn't displaying it. Both Electrum and the Blockchain explorer are showing that the balance is in the wallet, but core won't update, and because it's a descriptor wallet, I haven't been able to move the wallet to another Client because I can't access the private keys. Any help on how to get this balance out?

Comment: Are you able to abandon the transaction? (`abandontransaction` RPC if you use the command-line, right click on the transaction and choose abandon in the GUI)?

Comment: No, abandon transaction is showing up unclickable, command line is saying that the transaction isn't eligible for abandonment